# Backbone POST JSON

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone and got the GET working with a test endpoint e.g.,

```
var Attributes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '//127.0.0.1:8080/blah'
});

var AttributeListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.page',
  render: function () {
    var that = this;
    var attributes = new Attributes();
    attributes.fetch({
      success: function (attributes) {
        var template = _.template($('#attribute-list-template').html(), {attributes: attributes.models});
        that.$el.html(template);
      }
    })
  }
})
```

However, the real endpoint requires a POST with JSON payload and I can't get the syntax to work. I tried something like this

```
var AttributeListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.page',
  render: function () {
    var that = this;
    var attributes = new Attributes();
    attributes.fetch({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      data: '{ "searchtext": "abc" }',
      success: function (attributes) {
        var template = _.template($('#attribute-list-template').html(), {attributes: attributes.models});
        that.$el.html(template);
      }
    })
  }
})
```

@Rusty, the URL works fine with or without http, browsers nowadays handle it properly. After digging a bit more, it seems like it is a CORS issue. I know that the endpoint has set Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* but only for POST request and I don't think the request is being set properly, here's what I got from Chrome debug

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8080/blah
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
{ "searchtext": "abc" }:
```

From the console log

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/blah. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Hmm. That url doesn't look right, it looks like you are using the relative path syntax for a full path. Try changing the `url` to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/blah`, or else just `/blah`, one or the other. But you said it is working with a GET request. What are the results you are getting? Is the `success` callback being fired? Have you thrown a `console.log` or `alert` in the success callback to check, or do the server logs tell you that it isn't working?

Comment: See updated question for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said this is a **CORS** issue.

Specifically on `POST` `PUT` and `DELETE` requests the browser actually performs 2 requests.

What happens under the hood is that, before the real request, the browser sends a preflight `OPTION` request which is like asking the server for permission to make the actual request.
(Please checks on the server log which type of request comes from the browser)

To allow CORS request the server must correctly handle this scenario and respond to the `OPTION` request with a set of `CORS Headers` like those:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://some.another.domain
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

In the CORS Headers (all begin with Access-Control-Allow-*) the server specifies the following permissions:

- Which domain is allowed to perform the request, it can be `*` to allow any external domain.
- Which HTTP Methods are accepted from those domains.
- Which Request Headers are accepted, you can add all the headers you need. 
  For example to handle HTTP Authentication between different domains, which is a common scenario using external API you'll need to add the Authorization header.

If the server responds correctly to the `OPTION` request the browser will performs the the actual request.

This is a guide to correctly handle CORS Requests for Rails but the it easily applies to all the server side languages/frameworks: http://leopard.in.ua/2012/07/08/using-cors-with-rails/

Answer (score 0):

Rustytoms in his comment is correct. You don't have to set the entire url, you could just write `/blah` but I think the problem you are having is different.

By default, when you call fetch on a new model Backbone will generate a GET request to get the information following the REST principles. To check whether the model is new Backbone uses the `model.isNew()` method, which basically just checks if the model has an id. If you call the `save()` method on a Model then Backbone will generate a POST request to '/users', and if the model is not new it will generate a SYNC request to '/users/:id'.

This methods delegate all the functionality to the `Backbone.sync()` method. So what you can do if you back end API does not follow the REST principle is to replace the `fetch()` method in your model with an AJAX call, or create a new one. On the 'success' of the AJAX request you can use`model.set()` to save your attributes to the model.

I suggest you read the [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) to get to know this methods since everything is very clear.